# Visual Studio Code using Regular expression to replace text with new line

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Hi I got about a 1000 lines of data, what I need to do is using regular expression mode on visual code to find "),(" and replace with a new line after the comment. Is this possible, below is an example of what im trying to achieve.

```
(test, null, null, 1),(test1, null, null, 2)
```

into

```
(test, null, null, 1),
(test1, null, null, 2)
```

Comment: @JamesThorpe, yes this is correct

Comment: Do you even need regex for that?  Would have thought the bog-standard find/replace should just find `),(` without issue

Comment: How would you implement the new line @JamesThorpe

Comment: Sorry, yes - was forgetting you needed that mode turned on to do more complex replace statements - was concentrating on the find part :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search:

```
\([^\)]*\),
```

`\(`, `\)` and `,` are literals

`[^\)]*` matches all characters which are not an `)`

Replace:

```
$0\n
```

`$0` is the back reference for the whole match

`$x` (e.g. `$1`) would be the back reference for a group marked by `(` and `)`, but is not required here as kennytm pointed out

`\n` is a newline

Comment: You could use `$0` to refer to the whole match, thus no need to add the capturing group `(…)`.